# How to Fill a Html Tabular form Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

This is the html form which redirects the asp page. I want to fill the form using javascript. fields are : regno, sch, cno. 
how can i fill the fields and submit using Javascript?

[image: this is the image of html code click here]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details in the question and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer 
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more detail and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: actually this is complete question.